# Nothing happens until the external python command finish running in java

Tags: java, python

I have a `logText(String text)` function which basically shows some text in a text area. I need some text to be shown before running the external python command. But the text is shown after the execution of external python command.
Here is my code.

```
    logText("Please Wait Until The Testing Is Finished");
    logText("Starting Testing...");

        String command = "python3 python/Predict.py";

        try {
            String line;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            error.close();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            input.close();

            OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            printStream.println();
            printStream.flush();
            printStream.close();
            logText("Images Created At Output Directory");
            logText("Testing Completed");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MasterFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MasterFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

My `logText()` function.

```
private void logText(String logText) {
    if (logArea.getText().equals("")) {
        logArea.setText(">>> " + logText);
    } else {
        logArea.append(System.lineSeparator() + ">>> " + logText);
    }
}
```

How can I show the text in the text area before execution of python command?

Comment: can you add logText function here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing is a classic example of running long-running code on GUI thread and as a result, freezing the main thread. The solution is the same as always (no matter what language or framework): run the long-running work in a background thread such as a new Thread(...) or a SwingWorker.

for example:

```
logText("Please Wait Until The Testing Is Finished");
logText("Starting Testing...");
String command = "python3 python/Predict.py";

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            String line;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            error.close();

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            input.close();

            OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
            PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            printStream.println();
            printStream.flush();
            printStream.close();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Here, we can safely update the GUI
                    // because we'll be called from the
                    // event dispatch thread
                    logText("Images Created At Output Directory");
                    logText("Testing Completed");
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(MasterFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MasterFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}).start();
```

p.s. as you can see in the comments the last two commands in the new thread needed to be called with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.

Comment: This is not a thread-safe answer -- you're calling `logText(...)` from within a background thread, and this can cause the GUI to crash unpredictably.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right, I only wanted to point out the concept. for now I will remove these two lines and fix it in an update soon.

Comment: You could queue them onto the event thread from within your background thread via `SwingUtlities.invokeLater(...)`, and call the `logText(...)` method from within the Runnable passed into the invokeLater method

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so at the end of the code were it is closing the printStream I should call those two lines in SwingUtlities.invokeLater(...) right?